# Spring Batch With Schedular

Tags: spring-batch

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI2TL.png)I am new to Spring Batch with Scheduler. Here my task is to read the data from one table and write it into another table.

I am randomly going through the blogs and different tutorials.

I don't know whether there is any direct approach read from database and write into database. I took this approach like 
Job 1 : Reads the data from the db using JdbcCursorItemReader, writing the data into a txt file using FlatFileItemWriter.
Job 2: Read the data from the txt file using FlatFileItemReader, multiResourceItemReader and writing the data into another table using HibernateItemWriter.

I am using a scheduler and it is going to run the batch for every 20 sec.

In this approach for the first run it is working fine. For the second run(after 20 sec), I am updating the data in the database(base table) but it is not writing updated data into the file and database.

Here is my configuration & code`package com.cg.schedulers;

```
public class UserScheduler {
    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher launcher;
    @Autowired
    private Job userJob;
    @Autowired
    private Job userJob2;
    private JobExecution execution1,execution2;
    public void run() {
        try {
            execution1 = launcher.run(userJob, new JobParameters());
            execution2 = launcher.run(userJob2, new JobParameters());
            System.out.println("Execution status: " + execution1.getStatus());
            System.out.println("Execution status: " + execution2.getStatus());
        } catch (JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobRestartException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JobParametersInvalidException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

### Xml Configuration

```
<import resource="spring-batch1.xml" />
<import resource="springbatch-database.xml" />
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.cg"/>

<!-- Reading data from -->
<bean id="itemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"
    scope="step">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="sql" value="select UserId, UserName, Password from USER" />
    <property name="rowMapper">
        <bean class="com.cg.mapper.UserRowMapper" />
    </property>
</bean>


<!-- ItemWriter writes a line into output flat file -->
<bean id="flatFileItemWriter" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemWriter"
    scope="step">

    <property name="resource" value="file:csv/User.txt" />

    <property name="lineAggregator">

        <!-- An Aggregator which converts an object into delimited list of strings -->
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineAggregator">

            <property name="delimiter" value="," />

            <property name="fieldExtractor">

                <!-- Extractor which returns the value of beans property through reflection -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.BeanWrapperFieldExtractor">
                    <property name="names" value="userId, username, password" />
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- ItemReader reads a complete line one by one from input file -->
<bean id="flatFileItemReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.FlatFileItemReader"
    scope="step">

    <property name="lineMapper">

        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.mapping.DefaultLineMapper">

            <property name="fieldSetMapper">
                <!-- Mapper which maps each individual items in a record to properties 
                    in POJO -->
                <bean class="com.cg.mapper.UserFieldSetMapper" />
            </property>

            <property name="lineTokenizer">
                <!-- A tokenizer class to be used when items in input record are separated 
                    by specific characters -->
                <bean
                    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.DelimitedLineTokenizer">
                    <property name="delimiter" value="," />
                </bean>
            </property>

        </bean>

    </property>

</bean>

<bean id="multiResourceItemReader"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.MultiResourceItemReader">
    <property name="resources" value="classpath:csv/User.txt" />
    <property name="delegate" ref="flatFileItemReader" />
</bean>


<!-- Optional JobExecutionListener to perform business logic before and 
    after the job -->
<bean id="jobListener" class="com.cg.support.UserItemListener" />

<!-- Optional ItemProcessor to perform business logic/filtering on the input 
    records -->
<bean id="itemProcessor1" class="com.cg.support.UserItemProcessor" />

<bean id="itemProcessor2" class="com.cg.support.UserItemProcessor2" />

<!-- ItemWriter which writes data to database -->
<bean id="databaseItemWriter"
    class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.HibernateItemWriter">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>


<!-- Actual Job -->
<batch:job id="userJob">
    <batch:step id="step1">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="itemReader" writer="flatFileItemWriter"
                processor="itemProcessor1" commit-interval="10" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>
<batch:job id="userJob2">
    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="multiResourceItemReader" writer="databaseItemWriter"
                processor="itemProcessor2" commit-interval="10" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
<bean id="myScheduler" class="com.cg.schedulers.UserScheduler"/>
<task:scheduled-tasks>
    <task:scheduled ref="myScheduler" method="run" cron="*/20 * * * * *" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

Please provide the direct approach if possible using hibernate.

[enter image description here][2]
Execution status: COMPLETED

Thanks,
Vamshi.

Comment: Any exceptions/logs that are occurring the second time?  Are you passing different identifying parameters the second time?

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for the reply. I am not getting any error. The scheduler is running the jobs for every 20 sec as expected but the job is not picking updated/newly created data. For the first run it is generating HQL queries but from second run it is not generating any queries.

Comment: What do the logs say?  If the job instance has been successfully run to completion, it won't be run again and Spring Batch will log this.

Comment: Hi Michael, I have uploaded the log image.
Please clarify my confusion.
My requirement is to read the data from one table and write into another table in certain interval. In that time interval i may update or insert new data in the base table. Whether is it possible with Spring batch with scheduler.

Thanks.